# Creating a poller using Google Cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to GCF, was looking through the documentation to implement a GC function(Javascript/nodejs) which polls an external REST service at around 1 invocation per sec. What are the possible ways/best practices to implement this?

1. I went through Cron option available and also pub/sub (pull) option, but I'm not sure this will serve my purpose. The CRON facility only have granularity at the minute level whereas I need to configure at every second level.
2. I also do not want to publish 60 messages/minute type hacky scenario and using subscriber-pull options. Not sure if this is even possible, but I see the subscriber can be limited to read max-messages etc., in pull mode.
3. setTimeout/setInterval is an option available to call, but this will retain the cloud function resources - not sure if this is a recommended practice.

Any recommendation as to how best to implement a simple poller from within Google cloud function using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no built in scheduling mechanism provided by Cloud Functions.  You'll have to schedule the invocation using some other scheduler that you provide.  You're correct that a cron-like solution probably won't be granular enough to get you an invocation every second, so you might end up having to dedicated create a server instance (maybe App Engine?) whose sole purpose is pinging the function at the frequency you choose.

Don't use setTimeout or setInterval.  They won't work for you.  (And they're almost never the right solution for anything running in Cloud Functions)

Comment: Having an AppEngine just for polling defeats the purpose of using google cloud functions :) . I was just hoping for a lightweight mechanism that go-along with Google cloud function

Comment: Not really.  You only need one server instance of App Engine here - it doesn't require your attention to scale up in order to handle more load like Cloud Functions can do automatically.  It only has to do something once a second, as opposed to potentially thousands of things per second.  This is really your best option unless you can find someone else willing to host your 1-ping-per-second requirement.